# C dynamic allocate struct within struct free()

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

I have two structs, "link_time" and "vehicle_information" which I am using in a traffic simulation plugin. I am having difficulty properly freeing (and allocating?) memory for the two custom structs I have created.

```
//global vardeclarations
//GLOBAL_VEHICLE_INFO contains all of the "vehicle_information" structs             
//representing all of the vehicles within the simulation
vehicle_information_template* GLOBAL_VEHICLE_INFO;
int lengthGLOBALVEHICLE;

vehicle_information_template* TEMP_VEHICLE_INFO;

//struct definitions
typedef struct link_time{

     float link_duration;
     float timestamp;

}link_time_template;

 typedef struct vehicle_information{
     int id;
     int current_link_id;
     float start_time;
     link_time_template* ltt; //individual vehicle link travel times array

}vehicle_information_template;


//function to add new "vehicle_information_template" to GLOBAL_VEHICLE_ARRAY
vehicle_information_template* addToGlobalVehicleArray(vehicle_information_template* target_array, int array_length, vehicle_information_template new_vinfo){
    int k;

    //allocate space for temp holding array, both the 'vehicle_information' struct and the 'link_time' struct within 'vehicle_information' struct

    TEMP_VEHICLE_INFO = malloc( sizeof(vehicle_information_template) * (array_length+1) );
    for(k=0;k<array_length+1;k++){
        TEMP_VEHICLE_INFO[k].ltt = malloc( sizeof(link_time_template) * NUM_LINKS);
    }


    //copy contents so that target_array can be free'd and resized
    for(k=0;k<array_length;k++){
        TEMP_VEHICLE_INFO[k] = target_array[k];
    }

    //add the new vehicle_info to the end of the TEMP_VEHICLE_INFO(newly resized)
    TEMP_VEHICLE_INFO[array_length] = new_vinfo;

       //****BREAKS HERE *****
    //free target_array (GLOBAL_VEHICLE_ARRAY) so that it can be resized to one element larger
//free the struct in the reverse order, freeing 'ltt' first, as it is a member of the larger struct 'vehicle_info'
    for(k=0;k<array_length;k++){
        free(target_array[k].ltt);
    }
    free(target_array);

    //reallocate GLOBAL_VEHICLE to 1 size larger to accomodate new element
    target_array = malloc(sizeof(vehicle_information_template) * (array_length+1) );
    //allocate space for "link_time" struct within "vehicle_information" struct
    for(k=0;k<array_length+1;k++){
        target_array[k].ltt = malloc(sizeof(link_time_template) * NUM_LINKS);
    }
    //copy contents from temp array to global array
    for(k=0;k<(array_length+1);k++){
        target_array[k] = TEMP_VEHICLE_INFO[k];
    }
    //free temp array struct
    for(k=0;k<array_length;k++){
        free(TEMP_VEHICLE_INFO[k].ltt);
    }
    free(TEMP_VEHICLE_INFO);
    //return newly sized global array
    return target_array;
```

}

"vehicle_information" contains a pointer for the allocation of a dynamically sized array of "link_time". I've read in other stack posts that if I declare a pointer as the last member of my struct, then I can control this member as if it were a dynamic piece of memory (malloc, realloc, free). I also know that I need a free for every malloc, which I believe I have done correctly.

I malloc for the 'vehicle_info' struct and then the 'link_time' struct 'ltt' within 'vehicle_info'. I would assume I free in the reverse order, since 'ltt' is linked in memory to 'vehicle_info? But the HEAP complains and my program crashes when I get to the following line in the function 'vehicle_information_template* addToGlobalVehicleArray()':

```
    //free target_array (GLOBAL_VEHICLE_ARRAY) so that it can be resized to one element larger
//free the struct in the reverse order, freeing 'ltt' first, as it is a member of the larger struct 'vehicle_info'
    for(k=0;k<array_length;k++){
        free(target_array[k].ltt);
    }

    free(target_array);
```

Every time a vehicle enters the simulation, it should be added to the "GLOBAL_VEHICLE_INFO" array. Pseudo code below:

```
    ...
    //***vehicle enters network

    vehicle_information_template temp_v;
    int k;
    //set temp_v to the newly released vehicle's information so it can be added to GLOBAL_VEHICLE_INFO
    temp_v.id = qpg_VHC_uniqueID(v);
    temp_v.current_link_id = qpg_LNK_index(qpg_VHC_link(v));
    temp_v.start_time = -1.0;

    //allocate memory for temp_v.ltt
    temp_v.ltt = malloc(sizeof(link_time_template) * NUM_LINKS);
    //set link_duration and timestamp to dummy values
    for(k=1;k<=NUM_LINKS;k++){
        temp_v.ltt[k].link_duration = -1.0;
        temp_v.ltt[k].timestamp = -1.0;
    }

 //add temp_v to "GLOBAL_VEHICLE_INFO" using function
    GLOBAL_VEHICLE_INFO = addToGlobalVehicleArray( GLOBAL_VEHICLE_INFO, lengthGLOBALVEHICLE, temp_v);
    lengthGLOBALVEHICLE++;

    //free allocated temp_v.ltt (link_travel_time)
    free(temp_v.ltt);
```

If anybody has any solutions or suggestions about how I'm handling my pointers or memory,  I tried to be as symmetric as possible, I would be much obliged.

Answer (score 2):

I see the problem in the first lines of `addToGlobalVehicleArray` function - you allocate `TEMP_VEHICLE_INFO[k].ltt` memory but then you lost it overriding by `TEMP_VEHICLE_INFO[k] = target_array[k]` code line.

Also suggest to make you code more structurized - introduce separate functions `create_link_time_array()`/`free_link_time_array()`, `create_veh_info_array()`/`free_veh_info_array()` to move service code away from main control flow and make code more clear and readable. This will help you a lot to avoid such problems.

Or better - use C++ and forget this manual memory control hell.